# Change property on object inside a function in the own object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, scope, this

I create an object and set some functions to it, my question is, can I change a property value of this object inside a function that I attach to it?

Here is my code:

```
    var service = new Object();
    service.login = login;
    service.isUserAuthenticated = false;

    function login(userName, password, successCallback) {
        var requestBody = 'grant_type=password&username=' + userName + '&password=' + password;
        $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + 'token', requestBody)
            .then(
            function (response) {
                isUserAuthenticated = true;
                successCallback(response);
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
    }
```

I would like to change the value of isUserAuthenticated when the user login into the system, is that possible inside this login function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but can't you just do before the success callback service.isUserAuthenticated = true ?

Comment: Sure why couldn't you just set:  service.isUserAuthenticated = true

Comment: Which questions did you read? Please link them.

Comment: `isUserAuthenticated` is a property of `service`, not a plain variable. Treat it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind `login` to `service` as you have, `this` (if used in the body of the `login` function) will refer to the `service` object during the execution of `login`. However, in the subsequent callbacks defined inside the `login` function and passed as arguments to `.then()`, `this` will no longer refer to the service object once the callbacks are executed, so you'll need to either `bind` the service as the (`this`) context for callback, or else store it in a closure. Thus, you could rewrite your `login` function:

```
// binding 'this' to the service
function login(userName, password, successCallback) {
    var requestBody = 'grant_type=password&username=' + userName + '&password=' + password;
    $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + 'token', requestBody)
        .then(function (response) {
            this.isUserAuthenticated = true;
            successCallback(response);
        }.bind(this),
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

or else:

```
// storing the service as a closure
function login(userName, password, successCallback) {
    var requestBody = 'grant_type=password&username=' + userName + '&password=' + password;
    var self = this;
    $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + 'token', requestBody)
        .then(
        function (response) {
            self.isUserAuthenticated = true;
            successCallback(response);
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

In your case, the latter isn't strictly necessary, since you're already storing the service as a variable that is declared outside of the `login` function, and can simply assign `true` to `service.isAuthenticated`.

Additionally, if you are using ES6, the function literal (i.e., `function() { //... }`) you are passing as a callback to `.then()` could be written using fat-arrow notation, and the context binding will be performed automatically:

```
function login(userName, password, successCallback) {
    var requestBody = 'grant_type=password&username=' + userName + '&password=' + password;
    $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + 'token', requestBody)
    .then((response) => {
        this.isUserAuthenticated = true;
        successCallback(response);
    },
    (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```